# MongoDB + wiredTiger + compression - is compression done on client or server?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 2.8-rc0 supports compression via the *wiredtiger* storage engine, as described in the [release notes](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.4.1/architecture.html).

My question is: **is data compressed in the API at the client level, or on the server?** Basically I want to know whether enabling compression will reduce the bandwidth requirement over the network (and  as a side-effect increase throughput & reduce latency), if my server and client are sitting on different hosts. Or is this equivalent to running the old mmap storage engine on top of a disk with transparent compression, as discussed for example [in this jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-164)?

There is some information about the new storage engine [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/102461818738/announcing-mongodb-2-8-0-rc0-release-candidate-and), but I don't have much experience with mongoDB and I'm looking for feedback from somebody who has already experimented with this.

Comment: As said no, however, there are different forms of compression which could effect performance, the quick compression is designed to be exactly that and have almost no visible effect on performance, more high level stuff like gzip may have an effect

Comment: FYI, there is a relevant feature suggestion in the MongoDB issue tracker you can watch/upvote: [SERVER-3018: Compression of wire protocol](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3018). Any changes in the wire protocol (such as negotiating compression) will require driver updates as well.

Comment: Note: if your client apps are connecting to your MongoDB server via an SSH tunnel or VPN, you could enable compression at the network layer. Compression will add some CPU overhead, which generally isn't a resource constraint for MongoDB but may have a more noticeable impact on your application servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a topic for StackOerflow really so this really needs to be migrated. I'm assured they are when flagged as such so you get something.

The WiredTiger inclusion in MongoDB 2.8 ( Release Candidate as of writing ) is an alternate storage engine mechanism to the default base "mmap" solution that has been current up until this release.

Basically the "short" answer here is that the "compression" is handled by the server, and this is largely to address many concerns that that data storage format of MongoDB in previous releases has been quite excessive.

To relate to the "compression" capabilities between "client" and "server" ( meaning between hosts ), the existing protocol uses BSON over wire transfers ( optionally encrypted via SSL ) but the changes don't allow "over the wire" compression without external utilities.

So part of the point of the WiredTiger storage engine inclusion is all about reducing the file storage size and not really about network transfer.

Comment: I suppose as they say WT is a 'drop in replacement', and for this to work means the client side API isn't modified in any way. Hence all the changes are in the so-called 'storage engine'. It's a shame, as it wouldn't cost you extra to compress stuff over the wire!

Comment: @Luciano The wire protocol is already relatively "light" in comparison to many others. It is a binary form and is not HTML or JSON text which responds more readily to compression. The trade off is compression/decompression time vs the reduction in payload. Nothing yet, as the main concern has been directed at the data file size of MongoDB databases with the default legacy engine. If you have large "wire" payloads, then you might want to reconsider your approach. Perhaps accumulating data on the client. Broader question than what this asks.

Comment: Thanks; I suppose I had a very specific use-case: compressing time-series data. There's some interest on fast compression (e.g. lz4) which can often *both* decrease your payload and wall time for real data-sets. See for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzqlWUTndTo

Comment: @Luciano like I said. Your question does not encompass what you really seem to be asking. Look at [HVDF](https://github.com/10gen-labs/hvdf) as a reference project and feel free to ask more specific questions here if you need more clarification on the concepts. That means Post another question rather than keep posting comments. BTW You have enough reputation here to upvote helpful responses. The response here is you're welcome and say thank-you.

Comment: @NeilLunn The wire protocol uses BSON for messages, which is the same format as documents stored on the server. It is equally compressible ;-).

Comment: @Luciano Compression is not "free"; you pay for it in CPU. CPU is generally not a resource constraint for MongoDB, but often is a limiting factor for application servers. It would definitely be nice to have the option to control/negotiate compression for the wire protocol. I would also note the possible workaround of enabling compression at the network level if connecting via ssh tunnel or VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Since the compression is a feature of the storage engine then compression happens server side, thus not reducing bandwidth requirements.