# Mongodb 3.0.0: reduce bandwidth and disk storage

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

The situation: I am doing a spike to decide whether we can use Mongodb as our storage engine and I am asked to analyse disk storage and bandwidth usage. In particular, we are supposed to send 1TB of data per hour, so it is not really feasible without compression from the client side. Possibly related (tough the answers does not satisfy my need): [MongoDB + wiredTiger + compression - is compression done on client or server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487766/mongodb-wiredtiger-compression-is-compression-done-on-client-or-server).

Also, this question is inspired by `useCompression` of `MySQL` which exists since release 3.0.17 (probably dinosaurs were still around then), so it seems strange I cannot find anything similar for MongoDB.

The summary:

- how can I compress the amount of data sent by the client to the server?
- is it possible with the standard [Java driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/)?
- for disk storage on the server side, I still have to try, but Mongodb v3 comes with the `WiredTiger` storage engine, so I think I just have to set it up for my collection.

What I have done so far. I created a `json` file containing a realistic sample of the data we need to send from client to server and the file is around `320K` in size. I then used this snippet

```
URI uri = Library.class.getClassLoader().getResource("2437018803.json").toURI();
String search = Files.lines(Paths.get(uri)).collect(Collectors.joining("-"));        
Map object = mapper.readValue(search, HashMap.class);
try (MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));) {
      MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
      System.out.println(mongoClient.getMaxBsonObjectSize());
      MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test");
      List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
          Document doc = new Document();
          doc.put("name", "MongoDB");
          doc.put("type", "database");
          doc.put("count", i);
          doc.put("info", object);
          documents.add(doc);
      }
      collection.insertMany(documents);
 }
```

While this snippet is running, I was monitoring my Mongo server with [`iftop`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iftop) and in the end I read:

```
TX: cum: 20.2MB  peak: 208b 
RX:      3.34GB        208b
TOTAL:   3.36GB        416b
```

In my understanding, I think 3.36GB of data were sent through the network, which is compatible somehow (I write somehow because I do not really get how 3.36GB could become 5 on disk - how? What am I missing?) with `db.test.stats(1024*1024)` done on the client to check disk storage info:

```
> db.test.stats(1024*1024)
{
    "ns" : "mydb.test",
    "count" : 7752,
    "size" : 3875,
    "avgObjSize" : 524272,
    "numExtents" : 19,
    "storageSize" : 5049,
    "lastExtentSize" : 1315.140625,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "paddingFactorNote" : "paddingFactor is unused and unmaintained in 3.0. It remains hard coded to 1.0 for compatibility only.",
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "indexDetails" : {

    },
    "totalIndexSize" : 0,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So, to go back from where I started: how can I tell my client to send data in a compress way keeping the server able to understand the request? Is there a way? I do not care changing driver if that is required, I do not have to stick with the official driver if it does not fit my need.

Comment: The spec for the wire protocol has no mention of compression or a handshake where this could be negotiated so it looks like you will have to wrap the protocol to get compression http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/

Comment: @Martin: that was my belief. Maybe for this particular case CouchDB with its native (and default) support for compressed client-server communication is a better fit.

Comment: That's right - there's no compression of the data in flight by the drivers, and MongoDB doesn't have a mechanism for accepting compressed data. The data is compressed on disk if compression is on and the storage engine is WiredTiger. If you need to send 1TB uncompressed, and you have to compress it because the network can't handle the traffic, then you can't do it directly with MongoDB. You'll have to put some other layer on top or use a different solution.

Comment: @wdberkeley, may I ask you if there is any plan to support client-server compressed communication directly? And if so, how far in the future (roughly, I know plans are made to change)

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish - I know of no plans to add native compression to the wire protocol. You could configure the server and client to use TLS/SSL and have the TLS do the wire level compression.