# mongodb python compressed server connection

Tags: python, mongodb, zlib

I would like to connect to a mongodb server with python, but the input/output data to be connected. I don't mind if data is compressed in server. What I need is it to be compressed in transmission.

I suppose I should put some option when creating collection?

```
client = mongo.MongoClient('x.x.x.x')
db = client.rods
data = db.data
db.drop_collection(data)
db.create_collection(#which args to make it compressed and transmission compressed#)
```

Comment: Have you a code snippet to work with?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MongoDB + wiredTiger + compression - is compression done on client or server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27487766/4566520) it seems not possible to do it directly. A client/server architecture must be build in python to compress/decompress data and then to write directly from server side after decompressing.